How to Use PnP PowerShell to Connect to SharePoint Online and Reset Folder Permissions in a Specific Library?
I am currently trying to use PnP PowerShell to connect to SharePoint Online and reset the permissions of folders within a specific document library. My goal is to ensure these folders inherit their permissions from the parent library, but I'm encountering issues with my scripts.
Environment:
SharePoint Online
PnP PowerShell Module
Scripts Used:

Script to count items in a library using CAML query:

# Library Name
$libraryName = "Documents"

# Initialize the CAML query object
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery

# Set the ViewXml property
$query.ViewXml = @"
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
    <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>
</View>
"@

# progress tracking
$totalCount = 0

# Retrieve items
do {
    $listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -Query $query
    $totalCount += $listItems.Count
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

# Output total count
Write-Host "Total number of items in '$libraryName': $totalCount"


Script to reset permissions on a specific folder and its contents:

# Library and specific Folder
$libraryName = "Documents"
$folderUrl = "/THESITE/Documents/GGS" # Server-relative URL to the folder

# Get the folder as a list item from the specified library
$folderItem = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderUrl -Includes ListItemAllFields

# Reset the permission for the folder using the associated list item ID
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $libraryName -Identity $folderItem.ListItemAllFields.Id -InheritPermissions
Write-Host "Permissions reset for: $folderUrl" -ForegroundColor Green

# To avoid threshold issues
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -FolderServerRelativeUrl $folderUrl
foreach ($item in $items) {
    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $libraryName -Identity $item.Id -InheritPermissions
    Write-Host "Reset permissions for item: $($item.Id), Name: $($item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef)" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Write-Host "All permissions reset." -ForegroundColor Green

Any recommendations on these scripts or alternative approaches to achieve the expected result?
Thank you in advance for your help and insights!
The error I always get using the CALM query is:
Get-PnPListItem: C:\Users\JS\Desktop\company\Projects\SharePoint\ResetPermissions.ps1
Line |
  19 |      $listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -Query $query
     |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.

The error on the second script:
Get-PnPListItem: C:\Users\JS\Desktop\company\Projects\SharePoint\reset.ps1
Line |
  13 |  $items = Get-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -FolderServerRelativeUrl  …
     |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.

I'm connected to the Online SharePoint using the:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
And it is connected successful.
Any idea?

Did you resolve this?
